# NFS for embedded Linux with no Internet network

Tags: linux, embedded, nfs

I'm using a i.MX6 UL/ULL-based board; I'm using regularly NFS mode to debug my software.
To do so, I follow the NFS configuration guide and all works perfectly.
Supposing I'd like to perform NFS using the same Ethernet switch to connect my embedded board to my PC but avoiding to connect to Internet network, how can I do? When I tried to remove the internet connection, NFS didn't find the net.
Is it possible to create kind of "private network" to establish a connection only from embedded board and PC?

Comment: If both client and server are connected to the same switch you can create alias for your PC's interface connected to the switch and assign static address from a  new network which doesn't overlap with existing one. Then on the device assign another static address from the same new network. They should see each other. But generally, it depends on your network topology and this is not a programming issue.

Comment: Could you give me further detail about? Is there a tutorial or other documentation to set it for Linux embedded boards?